# Saving grayscale image as it appears in jet colormap

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, octave

I have grayscale satellite image which is processed from spectral data (band classifications). If i use jet colormap in imshow it will show absolute colormapped image. But if i try to imwrite in particular place it is saved like a bluish image. I saw one example in matlab central, but i didnt get. can anyone help me to write my image with colorscaled image.

Matlab central link: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/25026-saving-grayscale-image-as-it-appears-in-jet-colormap-of-imagesc

there accepted answer link is : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943

I have tried many times, this will show colormaped images in plots (imshow) they didnt write anywhere with colormaped. Now i want to write my image with colormaped.

example code:

```
I= imread('image path');
imshow(I,'colormap',jet);
imwrite(I,'path','jpg');  /not working
```

or

```
imwrite(I,jet,'path','jpg');  /not working
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Not how I would like, but try. Last comment before I sleep :)...
`imwrite(rgb2ind(img1,1e-2,'dither'),colormap(jet),'someImg.jpg');`

Comment: Not working. Error using dither>parse inputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `imshow` the colormap is always adjusted to the range of values in your image. `imwrite` however assumes your image has a value range of [0,1] if you are using `single` or `double` data types. Try to scale your image to the range [0,1] before saving.

If you provide a colormap in the call to `imwrite`, MATLAB assumes you are using an indexed image. Thus you will have to convert the image to the indexed format first. The following snippet worked for a test image `I` of mine:

```
% scale to [0,1]
I = I - min(I(:));
I = I ./ max(I(:));

% Create indexed image
[J,~] = gray2ind(I);

% Save image
imwrite(J,jet,'path','jpg');
```

Comment: sorry. How to do this for my image. any example please!

Comment: Assuming you have an image `I` it can easily be scaled to [0,1] by subtracting the minimum and then dividing by the maximum. i.e. `J =  I-min(I(:)); J = J ./ max(J(:));`

Comment: No, same output I am getting.

Comment: I added a second paragraph with further information and some example code to my answer. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773053/saving-grayscale-image-as-it-appears-in-jet-colormap/26773759#26773759/) worked well for me, but later I found out that some images were still scaled slightly different way from `imshow`.

However, I might found a reason of an original problem. Just after Matlab starts, its default colormaps (including 'jet') are set to 64 colors (64x3). Then, if any image is shown with a colormap, for example if `imshow('cameraman.tif'), colormap('jet')` is executed, all default colormaps become 256x3 (can be verified with `jetMap=jet;` before and after). Then it might happen that an image was written with a colormap different from the one applied to image figure (for example, if a figure called after `imwrite`).

Finally I found this solution (no image pre-scaling needed):

```
% Create indexed image, explicitly using 256 colors
imInd=gray2ind(im,256);
% Convert indexed image to RGB using 256-colors jet map
jetRGB=ind2rgb(imInd,jet(256));
% Save image
imwrite(jetRGB,'jet.png');
```

The images I used have the same color scale now, both the saved one and the one shown in figure.